# Logstash produce duplicates

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logstash-configuration

My goal is to import data from MySQL table in the ElasticSearch index. MySQL table has about 2.5 million records, however after a while logstash inserts at least 3x times more data and don't stop.

The weirdest thing is that I try to generate sha1 signature of each message and use it as document_id to avoid duplicates

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/app/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://database.xxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/test"
    jdbc_page_size => 25000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    statement => "SELECT * FROM Actions"
  }
}

filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      require 'digest/sha1';
      event['fingerprint'] = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(event.to_json);
    "
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticbeanstalk-env:80"]
    index => "test"
    document_type => "action"
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how one of such events would look like content-wise? if there's a slight difference in any of the event properties, the SHA would be different, so will the id and hence why you get duplicates.

Comment: It's basically an customer event generated on page like action, ip, browser info, timestamp. So pretty much each record is unique. The problem is that logstash will produce much more data even without fingerprint

Comment: It may not be the cause, but you might try catching any ruby exceptions.